# React redux waiting for data from api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am doing register form using react and redux with  axios, thunk, and promises middleware. First i want to wait for list of users. Then i want to check that if user with that login and email exist if not post user. I have a problem with waiting for api fetching to complete and dont really now how to chain this.

Actions

```
export function fetchUsers(){
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch({type:"FETCH_USERS"});
    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type:"FETCH_USERS_FULLIFILED", payload: response.data});
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({type:"FETCH_USERS_ERROR", payload: err});
      })
  }
}

export function postUser(body){
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch({type:"POST_USER"});
    axios.post(url, body)
      .then((response)  => {
        dispatch({type:"POST_USER_FULLFILED", payload: response.data});
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
        dispatch({type:"POST_USER_ERROR", payload: err})
      })
  }
}
```

I want to fetch list of users and check when user is clicking submit button. I cant do something like that cause there is no `then()` method

```
this.props.dispatch( fetchUsers()).then(()=>{
 //checking my conditions
 // if all is ok
this.props.dispatch(postUser(body))
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you separating the `actions` from the methods that triggers the `api` than?

You could use `Promise` into `fetchUsers()` and `postUser()` and you can manage easily the promise from the api functions. Check this:

```
// Api promise function.
export function fetchUsers(){
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response.data);
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
  })
}
// Api promise function.
export function postUser(body){
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(url, body)
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response.data);
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
  }) 
}

// Actions file. 
// todo: integrate the next code into your action function.
let dispatch = this.props.dispatch; 
dispatch({type:"FETCH_USERS"});
fetchUsers().then(allUsersFetched => {
  dispatch({type:"FETCH_USERS_FULLIFILED", payload: allUsersFetched})
  //checking your conditions
  // if all is ok
  dispatch({type:"POST_USER"});
  postUser(body).then(user => {
    dispatch({type:"POST_USER_FULLFILED", payload: user});
  }).catch(err => {
    dispatch({type:"POST_USER_ERROR", payload: err})
  })
}).catch((err) => {
  dispatch({type:"FETCH_USERS_ERROR", payload: err});
})
```

Comment: Solved my problem and opened my eyes for new things. Thank you a lot it was really helpfull.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Helpful!! Bookmarked!